# How often do files in these Linux directories change?

Tags: linux, files, upgrade

I am currently looking for a Host-Based Intrustion Detection System to perform file integrity checks with. I have some files/directories to start monitoring with:

- /bin
- /sbin
- /usr
- /opt
- /lib64
- /root
- /etc (exclude passwd/shadow)
- /boot/grub/grub.conf (wanting to grub all /boot)

I am excluding log and cache files that change constantly.

I am aware that there are files and various programs within these directories, but I am having difficulty in finding out whether those programs change or not. In orther terms: how often are they updated or patched? How often does a user/administrator use/change them? Thank you.

Comment: So you basically want to write your own `rkhunter`?

Comment: Not quite; I am deciding upon certain HIDS and file monitoring software, such as AIDE, to monitor files, changes, and the integrity of those files. With this list, it can be put into AIDE to see how active they are. Unfortunately, I am unsure how to find how often those files are even updated or changed by system updates or by someone.

Comment: It seems that you would have to ask the administrator of the system this question. I don't believe there's an answer that isn't specific to a particular installation.

Answer (score 3):

In their comment @Kusalananda is right. Your question cannot be answered other than in a general way, because an answer to it would only apply to a specific OS' instance's configuration and work load.

What you need to install, in order to find out **which** files register **what** types of changes, and **how often** is basically "[tripwire](https://www.github.com/Tripwire/tripwire-open-source)" (TW), a FOSS tool for monitoring and alerting on specific file change(s) on a range of *nix systems. I used it extensively with Debian-based systems.

TW's implementation and tuning are very time-consuming, but the info you derive from is very VERY fine-grained. You can exclude any file (incl. logs, caches, ...) as long as said file is present on your system.  That was for "**which**" and "**what**".

For "**how often**", TW's csv type output would need to be custom-post-processed.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. For "how often", would it be safe to guess that updating and patching, or worse, hacking, could cause those changes? If not, what would be typical causes.

Comment: @RonAnkrah, any and every change would be recorded, including any change on files inside /proc and /tmp since last TW scan. Any hacking trace would be detected if said hacking resulted in file modification. TW is handy if you decide to watch certain files and to exclude others in an effort to carry out a post-mortem in case of server intrusion. Depending on context, sys-admins may set up automated TW scans every x hours with TW's scan-logs rotation, so you may have a more precise picture of when a file was changed and also how often. Not sure this is the right place to discuss this though.